# How to keep data input not temporary, but permanent?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I want to create a voice recognition app, when I use the code. The resulting input becomes temporary. How to keep data input not temporary, but permanent? Meaning if the application is closed the data entered there is still when the application is reopened.

my code

```
private String getTempFilename() {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        File tempFile = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

        if (tempFile.exists())
            tempFile.delete();

        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT,
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

        int i = recorder.getState();
        if (i == 1)
            recorder.startRecording();

        isRecording = true;

        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                writeAudioDataToFile();
            }
        }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

        recordingThread.start();
    }

    private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
        byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
        String filename = getTempFilename();
        FileOutputStream os = null;

        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int read = 0;
        if (null != os) {
            while (isRecording) {
                read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

                if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
                    try {
                        os.write(data);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Full [code](https://pastebin.com/jnAuLRzP) and [MainActivity](https://pastebin.com/2xmZUtDL)

Comment: @AndyDeveloper SharedPreferences is not for storing huge audio files. It's for *preferences*. He should look at writing it to a file or something, perhaps maintaining a database of files on the system.

Comment: @Michael yes you are right.That's why i deleted the post. :) I just read the text not showing the code. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Michael see my answer is it right or wrong please let me know your suggestions?

Comment: @Alfa Centaury see my answer

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Thanks for the answer, i will try

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy copy of your temp file when you close the application.

> For E.g. In your app you have your file with all the data now when you
>   exit from app in your **"onDestroy()"** you can create the another
>   copy of that file and use it.

Now the question raise in your mind what happens when user run the app first time.

**Here is the answer for that**. You can check the file is exist then take data from that file else do nothing for that.

Comment: Can you please give example code? Because the input data generated when opened in the PC is not visible whereas if opened in phone explorer seen